# Merge succeeds but output missing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, arccatalog

I have problems with Merge tool. I can't find the output file in ArcCatalog even though I refresh it. Output is shown in Results window but nothign happens if I click Add to display. Strangely, also Messages->View is empty but Inputs and Environments seems normal. I'm trying to merge shapefiles and these are in the same coordinate system and located in the same folder. I've also copied the folder where I have the files to be merged to a new location but it didn't help.

I saw ther was a similar question earlier but it has been closed, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182104/merge-success-but-can-not-find-and-display-in-arcmap

[image: This is what is shown in Results window]

Comment: Are you trying to save the output to a server location? What if you save it locally? Which version of ArcGIS are you using? If you disable background processing, which messages do you see in the progress window when running the tool??

Comment: Can you show the files you are trying to merge? what do they contain and how the are symbolized?

Comment: You should get an error message if the following happens but I'll suggest it anyway since it will block the tool from working.  Check your field mappings to see if one or more of your shapefiles have values that don't "fit" within the fields of the others, such as text that is too long or a different field type for the same named field.  In the field mappings of the tool you can change the output field characteristics or drop fields entirely.  You could also check to be sure all the shapefiles you are including are of the same type, be it point, line or polygon, in case an oddball snuck in.